# Is it possible to get weight reading from an HX711 Load Cell Amplifier via an FT232H

Tags: python

I have connected an [Adafruit FT232H Breakout](https://www.adafruit.com/product/2264?gclid=CjwKCAiAo4OQBhBBEiwA5KWu_8ALv1qIEFMU6_MV-RIOWDBVwZsVwA42Bcf3ep14bjZNkajP9msJuBoCjcoQAvD_BwE) to my PC. I have connected a load cell to a [SparkFun HX711 Load Cell Amplifier](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/13879) and wired that to GPIO pins C0 and C1 on the FT232H BOB.

Not finding any appropriate libraries to get weight reading from the HX711 via the FT232H, I attempted to hack together something in Python 3 to pull readings from the HX711.

According to the HX711 [data sheet](https://www.digikey.com/htmldatasheets/production/1836471/0/0/1/hx711.html), in order to get readings, "[w]hen DOUT goes to low, it indicates data is ready for retrieval. By applying 25~27 positive clock pulses at the PD_SCK pin, data is shifted out from the DOUT output pin. Each PD_SCK pulse shifts out one bit, starting with the MSB bit first, until all 24 bits are shifted out. The 25th pulse at PD_SCK input will pull DOUT pin back to high." All well and good, but the data sheet also indicates "[w]hen PD_SCK pin changes from low to high and stays at high for longer than 60µs, HX711 enters power down mode."

I have written the following loop in Python that toggles the PD_SCK pin:

```
import board
import digitalio
import os
import time

dat = digitalio.DigitalInOut(getattr(board, "C0"))
dat.direction = digitalio.Direction.INPUT
clk = digitalio.DigitalInOut(getattr(board, "C1"))
clk.direction = digitalio.Direction.OUTPUT

high = True
low = False

while True:
    clk.value = True
    clk.value = False
```

When I measure the duration of the pulse when PD_SCK is "high" using an oscilloscope, it is about 250 microseconds, which is longer than the 60 microseconds which shuts down the HX711.

I cannot find any documentation regarding increasing the "speed" of the FT232H BOB, so I am thinking that it is not possible to use the FT232H BOB to get weight readings from the HX711. Has anyone succeeded in doing so? If so, are you willing to share the code you used to do so?

Comment: According to [datasheet](https://github.com/sparkfun/HX711-Load-Cell-Amplifier/blob/V_1.1/datasheets/hx711_english.pdf), output data rates of HX711 are 10 Hz (default) and 80 Hz. [Sparkfun's library](https://github.com/bogde/HX711) for their board is written for Arduino, so you might be able to look at the source code and figure out how to translate it to Python.

Comment: Thanks bfris. Can you help me understand your comment regarding the output data rates of the HX711? How does the 10 Hz (default) and 80 Hz out put rates relate to the issue I've encountered regarding the slow speed of the FT232H?

Comment: Honestly, I didn't read your question and the datasheet that closely. I had an idea that you were trying to read too fast. But you're right that 60 usec time before is powers down is troubling if you're Python code seems to be much slower. If you are handy with an Arduino, it might be worthwhile to see if the Sparkfun library works well and what the o-scope traces look like.

Comment: Ok, thanks bfris. I sincerely appreciate your help.